# Shutdown of Pyside application stalls

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside, shutdown

I have a pyside application, which runs perfectly fine. I have during development of the application seen periods where the application got stuck while shutting down. But the error often was gone when I was finish with my update.

Now I have made a new update, and now the application stalls upon exit. All functionalities works as expected.

As I have seen the error from time to time, I may think its a raise condition on garbage collection? But I don't know.

My code is something like:

```
def main(args):    
    appQt = QtGui.QApplication("KalimbaScope")
    ex =  KalimbaScope(args)
    appQt.exec_()
    print "wow, it gets thos far !" 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Where KalimbaScope is my main aplication class

```
class KalimbaScope(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    #do a lot
```

and well you guessed it, when shutting down the application it prints out:

```
wow, it gets thos far !
```

Comment: It can be anything. Since you do not reveal what your MainWindow class is doing... nobody can know why the application does not exit. In the present form this is not a good question. Try to make a minimum workable example that shows the error.

Comment: This is a fair comment, however I have not been able to reproduce the error in a small example. Moreover I'm pretty certain that it's not "my" code that is stalling. I was asking for any hints that could aid me to an understanding of what is happening. One could argue that functionality of the Mainwindow is not that important as it is terminated when it exits the appQt.exec_(). I have verified that no other threads are running at the time of shutdown the last print statement is executed. Anyways thanks for the interest

Comment: No problem. Well if you are sure that your code is not stalling than PySide/Python/Qt/your OS must be broken. For me QMainWindow and PySide worked flawlessly so far as I can remember. Maybe you could reinstall everything. But I guess that nevertheless somewhere deep in your app something bad happens. Without the code nobody here can know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be due to a 3. party DLL i was using. 
I have not yet found the reason, but the DLL only fails when running from a pySide application.

I do think the DLL is the issue and is trying to get it fixed.